# how to trigger java aplication (java -jar <app_name> from Google GO / golang sub_process

Tags: java, go

I'm trying to trigger java command line application as a sub process from golang.
For some reason it failed and actually I do not get java APP interface when I start it from GO. It wait for few sec and terminate with error code "can not connect ... "
Here is a code I tried to use:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)
func main() {
    start_java_app_test()
}
func start_java_app_test() {
    cmd_prep := "java -Xmx2g -jar test_app.jar"
    cmd_output, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmd_prep).Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(vba_ssh_cmd_output)
}
```

If we try just to use -->  `cmd_prep := "java -version"`  <--
it  will fail again.
It should give me output like
<< snip >>
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
<< /snip >>

The normal syntax like -->  `cmd_prep := "ls -l"`  <--    works fine.
Any clue ? 
What might be the reason here ?
Thanks in advance,
.C

Comment: Note that the `Output` method will only capture stdout.  Output sent to stderr (like what `java -version` does) will end up going to `/dev/null`.  Using `CombinedOutput` instead might help a little, but probably doesn't solve the problem entirely.

Comment: > What is the exact error? 
When I try to use >> cmd_prep := "java -version" << there is no output .
I have tried to add '2>&1' to cmd_prep to re-route all but nothing happened .
The sam thing happened with python code ... but with python I was able to fix with some time.sleep() function .

> Is there a requirement for using bash not stated i the question?
Yes and no. The Java application we are using was triggered by shell one line syntax, that is idea behind to do same from golang .
> If not, then run Java directly.
No clue how to do that

Comment: @James, I will give a try to use CombinedOutput. Actually need to get somehow output to a string and from that I can parse, regexp

Answer (score 0):

It works very well with 'CombinedOutput'  :)

```
$ go run TestCombinedOutput.go 
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,

.C

Comment: for this to run, we need to have `JRE` in the system , am I right